# Save NSBItmapImageRep as grayscale png without alpha

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image-processing

I try to save NSBItmapImageRep without alpha channel. 
My code is:

```
NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:img];
NSColorSpace *targetColorSpace = [NSColorSpace genericGrayColorSpace];
NSBitmapImageRep *targetImageRep = [rep bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace:targetColorSpace 
                                                               renderingIntent:NSColorRenderingIntentPerceptual];

NSData* PNGData = [targetImageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
[PNGData writeToURL:url atomically:YES];    
[rep release];
```

But It doesn't work. It saves my image with type GrayScaleAlpha.
How to specify using alpha?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without using some external library. All grayscale color spaces include an alpha component in Cocoa and it doesn't seem like there is any option for saving alpha-less PNGs in ImageIO either.

Comment: Omz, what about Quartz 2D framework. As I see I can do it via this one?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, Quartz2D doesn't support saving images at all, that's the domain of ImageIO (`CGImageDestinationRef`), and as I said, I don't think it supports that.